is it possible to edit existing CMake targets in CLion from the UI?
I'm using CLion 2024.2.3
By using the IDE and studying the documentation I still haven't found a way to edit CMake targets from the UI. I would like to be able to add/remove/change targets for existing C++ source files. As far as I've seen, I can only add a new target if I create a new C++ source file.
